# Android setOnCheckedChangeListener runs twice

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

This is my code. What can ba a cause?

```
holder.favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                addFavorite(famous);
            } else {
                deleteFavorite(famous);
            }
        }
    });
```

When `isChecked=true`, firstly is run `addFavorite()` and after that `deleteFavorite()`.

When `isChecked=false`, firstly is run `deleteFavorite()` and after that `addFavorite()`.

Don't know why...

EDIT: When I scroll down/up my `ListView` it calls these methods too... Weird...

```
    private void deleteFavorite(final FamousTop40Ranking famous) {
        DeleteFavoriteData data = new DeleteFavoriteData(famous.getId());
        FavoriteDeleteApi.Factory.getInstance().deleteFavorite(data.getData())
                .enqueue(new Callback<StatusInfoModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<StatusInfoModel> call, Response<StatusInfoModel> response) {
                        showToast(mActivity, "Famous deleted from your Favorites list.");
                        famous.setFollowersCountry(famous.getFollowersCountry() - 1);
                        famous.setFollowersWorld(famous.getFollowersWorld() - 1);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<StatusInfoModel> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("deleteFavorite", mActivity.getString(R.string.something_went_wrong) + t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }




private void addFavorite(final FamousTop40Ranking famous) {
        FavoriteCountApi.Factory.getInstance().countFavorites()
                .enqueue(new Callback<CountFavoriteModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<CountFavoriteModel> call, Response<CountFavoriteModel> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (response.body().getCount() < 20) {
                                FavoriteAddApi.Factory.getInstance().addFavorite(String.valueOf(famous.getId()))
                                        .enqueue(new Callback<StatusInfoModel>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onResponse(Call<StatusInfoModel> call, Response<StatusInfoModel> response) {
                                                showToast(mActivity, "Famous added from your Favorites list.");
                                                famous.setFollowersCountry(famous.getFollowersCountry() + 1);
                                                famous.setFollowersWorld(famous.getFollowersWorld() + 1);
                                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(Call<StatusInfoModel> call, Throwable t) {
                                                Log.d("addFavorite", mActivity.getString(R.string.something_went_wrong) + t.getMessage());
                                            }
                                        });
                            } else {
                                showToast(mActivity, mActivity.getString(R.string.reached_max_favorites));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<CountFavoriteModel> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("countFavorite", mActivity.getString(R.string.something_went_wrong) + t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
```

`getView()` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_ranking_famous_single_item, parent, false);
    }

    final FamousTop40Ranking famous = famousModelList.get(position);

    holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

    holder.name.setText(famous.getName());
    if (mTab == 0) { // RankingFamousMainFragment.TAB_FAMOUS
        holder.followers.setText(String.valueOf(famous.getFollowersWorld()));
    } else {
        holder.followers.setText(String.valueOf(famous.getFollowersCountry()));
    }

    if (famous.getIsFavorite().get(0).getFavorite().equals("1")) {
        holder.favorite.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.favorite.setChecked(false);
    }

    Glide
            .with(mActivity)
            .load(famous.getPhoto())
            .fallback(R.drawable.bg_gradient)
            .error(R.drawable.bg_gradient)
            .centerCrop()
            .crossFade()
            .into(holder.photo);

    holder.favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    holder.favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                addFavorite(famous);
            } else {
                deleteFavorite(famous);
            }
        }
    });

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showToast(mActivity, mActivity.getString(R.string.famous_clicked, position));
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In getView. Move setonCHecked(null) before the if/else.

The reason this is hapening is getView might get called alot of times, in this case i think it is called because when you change state(check/uncheck) it redraws the button. And  in your getView you are calling setChecked which triggers the listener. Setting the listener to null before calling holder.favorite.setChecked(true/false) wont double trigger it.

About up/down issue- It is the same, when the view is of the screen  it is deleted. When it appears again it calls getView whichi triggers everything due to holder.favorite.setChecked(true)  activating the onCheckChangedLIstener

As an example:

```
holder.favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
holder.favorite.setChecked(true);
holder.favourite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // handle your logic
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be late for the party!.. but this is how I fix a double trigger on radio Buttons, in my case I have a RadioGroup, that helps with the behavior of a group of radio buttons.

When you click on a specific radio button you expect to trigger lambda expression in "setOnCheckedChangeListener", which is normal.

But when you "reset" the group and need that no radio button be selected, you usually call either:

```
radioGroup.clearCheck()
```

or

```
radioGroup.check(-1)
```

But when you do that, the listener receives 2 calls, the first is for the radio button that is going to be "unchecked",
the second call with the radio button id equals -1.

so what ai have done, and work to me is:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
    //If not -1, means that is a radio button that was been clicked (don't know yet is checked or not)
    if (checkedId > 0) {
        //Get radio button element
        val radio: RadioButton = group.findViewById(checkedId)

        // Preguntar por si esta checked == true ?
        if (radio.isChecked) {
            when (checkedId) {
                R.id.rb_1 -> {
                    viewModel.onSetPv(1)
                }
                R.id.rb_2 -> {
                    viewModel.onSetPv(2)
                }
                else -> false
            }

        }
    }

})
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not an issue! Why? Imagine you have a radio-group, and you select one of the options; if you rotate the device, the selected option should be stay selected. (It save the state. In fact, it works just like view-model)

But, when it could be a problem? At first state, when you didn't choose any option. How to solve it? Just add `if (checkedId > 0)` before you check the ids:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener((radioGroup, checkedId) -> {
    
    if (checkedId > 0) {
          // here check the ids
    }
});
```

The other situation that you can face a problem is, when you use a same radio-group for multitasks (like quiz app). In this situation, what I did was using view-model. I let the view-model take care of saving state and right after I check the Ids, I add `radioGroup.check(-1);`  example:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener((radioGroup, checkedId) -> {
    
    if (checkedId > 0) {
          // here check the ids

          // use viewModel
          
          radioGroup.check(-1);
    }
});
```